# How to get data from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I have to echo the specific values from array. We have 2 fields and I only need to fetch the name value.

My code is this

```
$fields = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'age' => $age,
);
```

I need to get the name only in the echo result. I have tried the following, but its showing the Array.

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: And what does `print_r($value);` gives you?

Comment: what's stored in `$name` and `age`? are these both arrays?

Comment: yes these both are array ...

Comment: @Joe Then you just want to use `$fields["name"]` to loop over the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$name` and `$age` both are array, use the `loop` over `$fields['name']`.

Try this:

```
foreach ($fields['name'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your `$name` and `$age` arrays are the same length and contain information related to each other in the same sequence?

In which case you might be better off organising it like this?

```
for($i=0;$i<count($names);$i++){
    $fields[$i]['name'] = $names[$i];
    $fields[$i]['age'] = $age[$i];}
```

and then

```
foreach($fields as $field){
    foreach($field as $key => $value){
        echo $key. ' = ' .$value. '<br/>';}}
```

**Edit**

you could also add a condition like this in case the arrays don't match

```
if(count($names)!=(count($age))){
    echo 'error';}
else{
    *insert rest of code*}
```

this will let you know if there are more name values than age values and vice versa